# How can I set the default position of a draggable element using Angular Material DragAndDrop?

Tags: javascript, angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material

I would like to set draggable elements' default position within a container.

Example: https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#restricting-movement-within-an-element

How can I position the element e.g. center-center?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Angular Material version 8, the following input is available:

> @Input('cdkDragFreeDragPosition') freeDragPosition: { x: number; y:
> number; }
>
> Sets the position of a CdkDrag that is outside of a drop container.
> Can be used to restore the element's position for a returning user.
>
> https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDrag

And an example can be found at the following:
[<s>https://angular-tft6n5.stackblitz.io</s>](https://angular-tft6n5.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 1):

just use normal css to position the elements.   check the stackblitz for the following https://stackblitz.com/angular/ovlyobmkdnk?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-axis-lock-example.css and here is the changed one https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-54uare?embed=1&file=app/cdk-drag-drop-axis-lock-example.html

```
.container {
    display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color:red;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}



.example-box {
  align
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  cursor: move;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: box-shadow 200ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
              0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
              0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.example-box:active {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
              0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
              0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}


<div class=container>
<div class="example-box" cdkDragLockAxis="y" cdkDrag>
  I can only be dragged up/down
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you present an example?

Comment: i quickly adapted the original with one box centered.with the original y restriction in place